# StackOverflowException with too many commands in script?

Tags: powershell, stack-overflow

I am creating a powershell script from a SQL query. The query creates a list of commands using the `New-Item` command. Total number of commands was about 450k, all exported to a `.ps1` file. I could successfully execute this script.

I later discovered that some of the commands failed, so I needed to add error logging. For each line, I added at the end:

```
-errorvariable $err; if ($err) {code to write to error log, confirmed working in another script}
```

Exporting this to `.ps1` and executing yields a `StackOverflowException`, it doesn't run any commands at all. During troubleshooting, I discovered that if I shorten the list of commands, the script will work. I can execute chunks of 62k lines, but if I execute more than 62469 lines, I get the exception. The really strange thing is that if I narrow down to the exact line at which the failure occurs, I can shorten the last command to a point at which the script will execute, then add one more character, and it fails.

Here's an example of one of the command lines:

```
New-Item -Path "C:\Temp\TestingFolder\TestingSubFolder\F\8F\D42D79CD440CE98D31E9A1353CAA3\6121094601.03.pdf" -Value "F8FD42D79CD440CE98D31E9A1353CAA3` 6121094601.03.pdf" -Type File -Force -errorvariable err
if ($err) {
    Add-Content "C:\Temp\AnalogVaultLog.txt" -Value ("$(Get-Date -format 'u')" + "`r`n" + 'New-Item -Path "C:\Temp\TestingFolder\TestingSubFolder\F\8F\D42D79CD440CE98D31E9A1353CAA3\6121094601.03.pdf" -Value "F8FD42D79CD440CE98D31E9A1353CAA3` 6121094601.03.pdf" -Type File -Force' + "`r`n" + $err + "`r`n") -Force
}
```

As I said, I can execute a 450k line script that doesn't have a secondary error-log statement on each line, and it works, and that script has far more characters and overall commands than the piddly 62470 line chunk that fails. What would be causing this exception?

Comment: `450K line script` just.. wat.  Why are you using powershell for this task?

Comment: Honestly it's just what I came up with. I have a bunch of metatdata in a database that matches a series of directories, and I need to recreate the directory structure from that metadata. I also need to do it repeatedly. The SQL query was a bit of a bear to write, but once done the idea was that it just spits out a script that I can execute to create the folder structure.

Comment: It sounds like you need some loops in that script.  I've never seen a script over a few thousand lines at most and if I did, it should've been re-written in a different language.

Comment: Seems like loops would introduce additional overhead; right now I'm just executing a command to create the file and another to write to a log. With a loop those same commands would need to be executed, but the iterator would have to be checked each time. 

Can you explain what is bad about having this many commands in one script? Do you know what limitation I'm up against? The execution time is acceptable at the moment, I just need it to run.

Comment: It's entirely and completely unnecessary, unreadable, and unmaintainable.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help me where I am right now. I'm trying to understand powershell so that I can make better decisions in the future about when and when not to use it. To that end, I need to understand what is causing this to happen.

Comment: Apparently, something within PowerShell is using stack-allocated memory to process (part of) script files, and the amount of lines you're throwing at it exceeds the stack size. (By default, this is 1 MB per thread.) To identify the memory allocation patterns that cause one "big" script to fail while another that's "big" in some other sense does not is an interesting exercise, but since PowerShell (before PowerShell Core) is closed source, not a very rewarding one. It's a lot better to abandon this strategy and focus on generating *data* that small scripts can process.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, that's very helpful.